# how to get the bottom position of the font on a swing widget?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, fonts

I am working on a little drag-and-drop Java GUI builder.

I'm dragging and dropping JLabels and JButtons on a panel and it's working fine.

Now I want the widgets to be aligned "correctly" next to each other based on the bottom of the font on the widget.

If I line them up at yPosition = 0, it looks like this:

```
My Label /-----------\
         | My button |
         \-----------/
```

But I need to line them up at yPosition = "bottom of their text", like this:

```
         /-----------\
My Label | My button |
         \-----------/
```

So my question is:  Given a JLabel or a JButton, how can I determine the yPosition coordinate of the bottom of the font on that widget?

I hope that's clear.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: look at component.getBaseline(..)

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks!  Exactly the pointer I was looking for.  Post this comment as an answer, and I'm happy to mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is

```
component.getBaseline(...)
```